# How to pass a file directory reference to DLL a function?

Tags: java, jna

How to pass a file directory reference to DLL a function?

We have a DLL with the function named setconfigpath and it receives a file directory, ex. "C:\Users\aaaa\Documents".

The only reference we have is this (this is the code used by the application that currently uses the DLL),

```
DLL SETCONFIGPATH (Lconfig_Path)
```

`SETCONFIGPATH (LPCSTR Lconfig_Path)` based on decompiler IDA

And I made an interface

```
JNAApiInterface INSTANCE = (JNAApiInterface) Native.load("sample.dll", JNAApiInterface.class,
            W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS
            );
  
public int SetConfigPath( IntByReference  conf);
```

to call this DLL in JAVA, but whatever type of variable I placed (whether String, int or IntByReference, etc.)

it always throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:426)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:361)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:265)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.SetConfigPath(Unknown Source)
    at SampleRunCode.main(SampleRunCode.java:27)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the DLL not specify the type for the `config_Path`?   If it's a string, it's probably expecting a pointer to a character array and you are passing it a pointer to an integer.  The memory error would be when it tries to read past the 4 bytes of int that you have allocated here.  I'd expect a `String` (or `WString` for WIndows unicode) would apply here.

Comment: SETCONFIGPATH (LPCSTR Lconfig_Path) based on decompiler IDA

Comment: Use a `String` in Java/JNA to map to a `LPCSTR`

Answer (score 0):

As you've noted in the comments, the argument type expects a `LPCSTR` (a pointer to an array of bytes interpreted as a C String).

```c
SETCONFIGPATH (LPCSTR Lconfig_Path)
```

You've mapped an `IntByReference` which is a pointer to a 4-byte block of memory that is very unlikely to represent a C string.  [The correct mapping](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/Mappings.md) of a `LPCSTR` is a `String`.

Your JNA mapping should be

```java
int SetConfigPath(String conf);
```